# Exact comparison in set lookup

Tags: c++, stl, insert, find, set

I've got a struct (say `Foo`) which contains simply strings and a double and I've created a set which also has a comparator class which compares a subset of those attributes. So my Declaration looks like: `std::set<Foo, FooComp>`

When I call `find()` would I expect all the attributes of `Foo` to be used as a key or would `FooComp` be used? I'm assuming the former.

The reason that I'm asking is that I've got an issue where an object which has been previously added is not detected in the set even though I've tried using `find()` to check it's presence. I can only assume that this has happened as there was a subtle difference in the double perhaps? The double attribute is not used in the comparitor but presumably forms part of the key.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think it's difficult to answer without actually seeing any code... Anyway, "exact comparison" and `double` should always ring a bell in your head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::set::find()` will use `FooComp`, as long as the double does not form part of that comparison, it should be fine.

`std::find` requires `operator==`, so again depends if you've define this and what that includes, as long as it does not include the double (or includes the double in a sensible way), then you're good.

So, depends what `FooComp` looks like and which `find` you call...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the distinction. It's the set `find()` that I'm calling and after a bit of trial and error inspired by all the responses, the problem turned out to be down to a problematic implementation of the Comparitor function operator. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

FooComp needs to represent a binary function that takes 2 references to Foo and determines if the left one is logically less than the right one.

```
struct FooComp
{
  bool operator()( const Foo& left, const Foo& right ) const;
};
```

and implement operator() with "strict ordering" thus

- `!FooComp( foo1, foo1 )`
- `FooComp( foo1, foo2 )` => `!FooComp( foo2, foo1 )`
- `FooComp( foo1, foo2 )` && `FooComp( foo2, foo3 )` => `FooComp( foo1, foo3 )`

Actually the first axiom can be deduced from the second so you only need the 2nd and 3rd axioms.

Comment: That's only one of the axioms it has to satisfy. `FooComp` must be a strict weak ordering, meaning it must be irreflexive (`!FooComp(x,x)`), antisymmetric (`FooComp(x,y)` implies `!FooComp(y,x)`) and equivalence (by transitivity, irreflexivity and antisymmetry) must be transitive as well. https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering

Comment: irreflexive can be deduced from antisymmetric.

Answer (score 1):

The comparator will be used to find the specified item in the set.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison class will be used to maintain the `set` sorted and to `find()` also.